# How do you find $\theta$ using the inverse?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find two solutions of the following equations, giving your answers in radians.
$$\sin \theta = \frac{1}{2}$$ 
$$\csc\theta = \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}$$ 
$$\cot\theta = -1$$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a right triangle with one angle $\theta$ and label the sides so that the sine of $\theta$ is $1/2$.  Figure out the other side.  Then ask yourself what $\theta$ has to be.  Then ask yourself what other quadrant this would work in.